# add alt attribute to href depending on the class

Tags: jquery

the default state is:

```
<a  href="./" class="dynamic dynamic-children menu-item"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Présentation</span></span></a>
```

so if class = rfr-opened add alt="open"

```
<a alt="open" href="./" class="dynamic dynamic-children menu-item rfr-opened"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Présentation</span></span></a>
```

so if class doesn't have rfr-opened add alt="close"

```
<a alt="closed" href="./" class="dynamic dynamic-children menu-item"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Présentation</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Note: an `a` element shall not have an `alt` attribute.

Comment: like bazmegakapa said, `<a>` elements don't have alt, it's more for `<img>`.  if you need it to reference the elements somehow, you could just add it as a class instead

Comment: I think you want to use `title`, instead of `alt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('a').attr('alt', 'closed');
$('a.rfr-opened').attr('alt', 'open');
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/9xLYV/

Answer (score 1):

Tried and tested: http://jsfiddle.net/eMagu/ (I used inspector to check the alt value)

jQuery one liner...

```
// set all menu items to closed, then filter just the open class and set to open
$('.menu-item').attr('alt','closed').filter('.rfr-opened').attr('alt','open')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$('.menu-item').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('rtf-opened')) $(this).attr('alt', 'open');
    else $(this).attr('alt', 'closed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines of  . . .

```
$('a.menu-item')each(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('rfr-opened')) {

        $(this).attr('alt', 'open');

    } else {

        $(this).attr('alt', 'closed');
    }
});
```

Comment: -1: a) You're setting `href` instead of `alt`.  b) You will be setting them all to the same value based on the last element pulled by `var href = ..`. It should be dynamic based on the class of each individual element.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
jQuery("#rfr-topnav a").click(function () {
$('#rfr-topnav a').attr('title', 'closed');
$('#rfr-topnav a.rfr-opened').attr('title', 'open');
  });
```